# Blank page on SilverStripe site-manager after migration to nginx and PHP5.4

Tags: php, nginx, silverstripe

I recently migrated an old SilverStripe 2.3 website from an old Apache 2.0 server to a fresh nginx with PHP 5.4.

Although I managed to resolve most of the problems and I have access to the admin/assets folder, I am still unable to access the important page of admin, the site-manager and the dashboard. When I try to go to the site-manager or the dashboard page I get a blank-white screen with no errors.

Can anyone advise why this is happening?

**Nginx logs**

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Controller::handleRequest() should be compatible with RequestHandler::handleRequest($request) in /var/www/mydomain/sapphire/core/control/Controller.php

call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method Hierarchy::extraStatics() should not be called statically in /var/www/mydomain/sapphire/core/model/DataObjectDecorator.php
```

Comment: new version of php are more restrictive when it comes to coding standards. You need to fix those errors

Answer (score 3):

SilverStripe 2.3 will not work on PHP 5.4.

SilverStripe 2.3 was developed on PHP 5.2. The sapphire core uses many bits of PHP 5.2 code that were deprecated or removed in PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.4.

You will either need to upgrade your SilverStripe version, or move the website to a web server that supports an older version of PHP.

A few notes.

Silverstripe 2.3 was released [2009-02-23](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/changelogs/2.3.0).

The last update for 2.3 (2.3.13) was released [2012-02-01](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/changelogs/2.3.13).

2.3 is no longer supported.

Silverstripe 2.4 was released [2010-05-05](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/changelogs/2.4.0).

The last update for 2.4 (2.4.10) was released [2013-02-19](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/changelogs/2.4.10).

2.4 will no longer be supported after [2015-03-31](http://www.silverstripe.org/blog/silverstripe-2-4-end-of-life-announcement/).

As of writing the latest version of SilverStripe is 3.1.8. I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of SilverStripe. It might be difficult depending on the amount of custom code and modules in your site.

As for one of your specific errors:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of Controller::handleRequest() should be compatible with RequestHandler::handleRequest($request) in /var/www/mydomain/sapphire/core/control/Controller.php
```

As the error says, the `Controller` function `handleRequest()` should have the same amount of parameters as the `RequestHandler` function `handleRequest($request)`. Try changing the `Controller` function declaration to `handleRequest($request)`.

This may cause more errors, or you may have many more errors like this to fix. This is why I suggest upgrading instead of trying to edit the sapphire code with fixes.

Comment: https://github.com/sunnysideup/silverstripe-upgrade_silverstripe is a good tool for semi automatic upgrade from 2.4 to 3.0 and  3.1. If you have any Umlauts in your DB you'll run into troubles, cause there was a change from 2.3 to 2.4 handling the encoding in DB. See http://www.silverstripe.org/community/forums/migrating-a-site-to-silverstripe/show/5849?start=16 for a possible solution.